# Haskell function to check emptiness of regular expression

Tags: haskell

Hi I have the following data type for a regular expression:

```
data RE a            -- regular expressions over an alphabet defined by 'a'
= Empty          -- empty regular expression
| Sym a          -- match the given symbol
| RE a :+: RE a  -- concatenation of two regular expressions
| RE a :|: RE a  -- choice between two regular expressions
| Rep (RE a)     -- zero or more repetitions of a regular expression
| Rep1 (RE a)    -- one or more repetitions of a regular expression
deriving (Show)
```

and I need to devise a method to check if that regular expression contains an Empty string. Such as (Rep (Sym 'a' :+: Sym 'b')) would be true and (Sym 'a') would be false.
How would I go about making this method to return a boolean?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Questions along the lines of "I want to do X; can someone tell me how to write my code?" are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please see [help/on-topic] for more details. Note that if your question is, "I want to do X and I tried approach Y but it didn't work; can anyone help me figure out what I did wrong?" then that question is on-topic on Stack Overflow, and you'll find many people willing to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Computing Salomaa's Empty Word Property (sometimes also called "nullable") is typically done by putting the regular expression into a normal form which takes advantage of algebraic properties to remove redundant Kleene stars and then checks if there is a star operator still in the expression or if the expression has or is itself `Empty` as you've defined. Here is an [example](https://github.com/subttle/regular/blob/504094878a39424d0ee6b973d1f3767cdbb81d23/src/RegExp.hs#L418).

```
-- decide if the language defined by r contains ε, i.e.
-- nullable (r) ⇔ ε ∈ ℒ(r)
-- Also know as Salomaa's Empty Word Property (EWP)
nullable ∷ (Ord s) ⇒ RegExp s → Bool
nullable = nullable' . normalize
  where nullable' Zero     = False
        nullable' One      = True
        nullable' (Lit  _) = False
        nullable' (α :| β) = nullable' α || nullable' β
        nullable' (α :. β) = nullable' α && nullable' β
        nullable' (Star _) = True
```

Adding a case for `Rep1` would look like `nullable' (Rep1 α) = nullable' α`.

Comment: I don't know why I originally was thinking of `Rep1` as the "optional" operator (typically written `?`). If that were the case it would then be `True`. In the case of the positive closure, I think it would be something like a fold over the repeated concatenations but because we know it is repeated concatenation of the same expression we can instead just check it once with `nullable' (Rep1 α) = nullable' α` but I'll think carefully about that first before I make an edit.

Comment: That's correct and follows form the equality `L+ = L* L`. In a sense `L+` is "syntactic sugar" in regexps, and not a real primitive.